# how to determin the time complexity of this c program

Tags: c, algorithm, time-complexity

```
void mystery2 (int n)
{
 int i;
 for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    double x = i;
    double delta = 1 / (double)i;
    while ( x > 0 )
      x -= delta;
  }
return 0;
}
```

How to determine the time complexity of this program using tracking tables like here http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~vernon/cs367/notes/3.COMPLEXITY.html#application and not by guessing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each iteration, initially you have `x=i`, then `x` is decremented by `1/i` each time. So this will be repeated `i/(1/i)==i^2` times.

So, for each iteration of `for(i=1;i<n;++i)`, the inner part has a complexity of `O(i^2)`. As `i` grows from 1 to n it's just like adding `(1^2+2^2+3^2+...+n^2)`, which is roughly `n^3/6`. Thus it's `O(n^3)`.

---

```
    Outer loop(for)          Inner Loop
    I=1                      1
    I=2                      4
    I=3                      9
    ...                      ..
    I=N                      N^2
 TOTAL_                      ~N^3/6
```

Comment: `Sum[n^2,{n,1,N}]` should be `(n+1)(2n+1)n/6`

Comment: oh 10x you even made a table for me! :P but is there any "mathematic" way to get i/(1/i)==i^2 how you got this? because it steel feels like it's kind of "guessing".

Comment: @user1980750 initial value of `x` is `i` right? in the `while` loop, `x` is decremented by `1/i`each time right? So for `x` to be `0`, theoretically you need `i/(1/i)=i^2` which is *mathematical*. Due to precision loss from floating number arithmetic, you might need to do it a bit more or a bit fewer time. But that should not change the `O(n^2)` bound for this inner loop.

Answer (score 2):

This is relatively straightforward: you need to determine how many times each of the two nested loops executes, and considering the complexities together.

The outer loop is a trivial `for` loop; it executes `n` times.

The inner loop requires a little more attention: it keeps subtracting `1/i` from `i` until it gets to zero or goes negative. It is easy to see that it takes `i` iterations of the `while` loop to subtract `1` from `x`. Since `x` is initially set to `i`, the total time taken by the inner loop is `i^2`.

The total is, therefore, a sum of `x` squared, for `x` between `1` and `n`.

[Wolfram Alpha tells us that the answer to this is `n*(n+1)*(2n+1)/6`](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20of%20x%5E2%20for%20x%20between%201%20and%20n)

This expands to `n^3/3 + n^2/2 +n/6` polynomial, which has the complexity of `O(n^3)`.

Comment: Although you don't have to look up the formula. It's most natural to `guess` that it is at `O(n^3)`.

Comment: @phoeagon I agree, a guess would be correct here. However, the OP asked not to guess, so I asked the alpha to do the calculations for me.

Comment: thank you, I think i'm understanding the thought behind the second loop analyze.. but is there any mathematic way to get this answer? because we learnt in class to use a k variable.. and then get k==i^2